# Placement of a badge in iphone app

Tags: ios, user-experience

I have a special case in my iphone app where I have to display a badge on a tappable UI element and not in the tab bar ... is that acceptable ? I read the iOS guidelines and it says that a tab bar can display a badge (red oval) but they didn't mention any point stating that it should be placed specifically there (tab bar)

And if that is a bad UX practice, should I design a custom icon that looks like the badge and use it in my specific case ?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If they say a badge can be shown in the tabBar this does not mean that it can't be shown somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This is not uncommon and definitely not a bad practice. Badges are not used only for navitagation events (in tabbar).

If something is not forbidden by the guidelines, then it's permitted.

However, be sure the application still follows basic iOS design and you don't implement it in some non-standard way if stardard solution would be also possible.

For example, look at the iOS Mail application. It's a split view where every mail box in the main controller has a number with unread messages. Well, that's basically a badge.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that, I recommend you to use this customBadges: http://www.spaulus.com/2011/04/custombadge-2-0-retina-ready-scalable-light-reflex/?lang=en

Comment: This is wrong. You can do it. The class you are linking is doing what you say is not possible.

Comment: I though was clear that by "You can't do that" I was saying "You can't do that with the standard API", don't troll me, please...

Comment: Thanks for your answers ... so I would go for the normal badge (red oval) ... I don't want to confuse the users.